# Python & Selenium: Unable to find class using x-path

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python & Selenium to automate the sending request to add new connections in linkedin. Currently, I have the following problem:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[contains(@class, 'reusable-search__entity-results-list list-style-none')]"}
(Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)

Here is the element

< ul class="reusable-search__entity-result-list list-style-none">

Following is the script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\Softwares\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

#Login ID /Email Id
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_key"]').click()
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('session_key').value='LinkediN-Email'")

#password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_password"]').click()

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('session_password').value='LinkedPassword'")

#signin button click
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/section[1]/div/div/form/button').click()


#destination URL
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?origin=CLUSTER_EXPANSION&sid=bl!')

time.sleep(1)

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

time.sleep(1)

#Error in SkillSelection find element by XPath unable to find the class
skillsSection = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'reusable-search__entity-results-list list-style-none')]")
print(skillsSection)

#working code iterating through list and printing elements
for li in skillsSection.find_elements_by_tag_name("li"):
    #print(li.text)
    Connect_btn_contents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('artdeco-button__text')
    the_one_you_want = [x for x in Connect_btn_contents if "Connect" == x.text][0]
    the_one_you_want.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    Send_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Send']")
    print(Send_btn)
    Send_btn.click()


driver.close()
```

What can be the Issue and the correct solution of the issue?

Comment: remove the sensitive information from the code

Comment: It's just a random email I choose but I will edit it Thanks!!